# Problem when transforming a generic type which is an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics, higher-order-functions

I've built a generic repository which returns the resources I ask for. This is working just fine until I've tried to perform a grouped request by wrapping several fetch calls into a DispatchGroup. The repository is a generic class which indicates the return type.

I'm storing the response of each individual fetch to a dictionary, once all of them are ready I'm transforming the dictionary into the expected return type.

The problem comes when the generic is of type [Something] (i.e. T == [Something])

```swift
    public typealias RepoCompletion<T: Codable> = (Result<T?, Error>) -> Void

    public func fetch<T: Entity>(_ resources: [FetchResource<T>], completion: @escaping RepoCompletion<T>) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [unowned self] in
            let group = DispatchGroup()
            let valueSyncQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Repo.ValueSync")
            var values = [String: T]() 

            for resource in resources {
                group.enter()
                self.localDataSource.fetch(resource) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        if let value = value {
                            valueSyncQueue.sync {
                                values[resource.description] = value
                            }
                        }

                    case .failure(_): break
                    }

                    group.leave()
                }
            }

            group.wait(timeout: .now() + 10)
            let flattenedValues = resources.compactMap({ values[$0.description] }).flatMap({ $0 })
            completion(.success(flattenedValues))
        }
    }
```

The above code doesn't compile. The error says `Member 'success' in 'Result<_?, Error>' produces result of type 'Result<Success, Failure>', but context expects 'Result<_?, Error>'`. I think the problem comes because the generic type is an [] and the compiler needs help.

Check out the types when debugging:

```
(lldb) po type(of: resources.compactMap({ values[$0.description] }))
Swift.Array<Swift.Array<Schedule>>

(lldb) po type(of: resources.compactMap({ values[$0.description] }).flatMap({ $0 }))
Swift.Array<Schedule>

(lldb) po type(of: flattenedValues)
Swift.Array<Swift.Array<Schedule>>
```

I don't understand why the expression `let flattenedValues = resources.compactMap({ values[$0.description] }).flatMap({ $0 })` has different types for the left side and the right side once evaluated :S

Let's say T == [Schedules]. I expect `values` to be [String: [Schedules]]. Then when `.compactMap` I expect a result of [[Schedules]] and finally the `.flatMap` to return [Schedules] (i.e. T). But I'm missing something or I don't get it.

If I try to help the compiler and force cast the flattenedValues to be as! T, it crashes returning

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array' (0x1058073b0) to 'Schedule' (0x1044ac928).
>   2019-10-17 09:48:14.585362+0200 Chicisimo[86448:2426001] Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array' (0x1058073b0) to 'Schedule' (0x1044ac928).

Which I don't really understand because `T` is of type `[Schedule]` and not of type `Schedule`.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us the declaration of `RepoCompletion`?

Comment: I've edited the question adding it.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you are trying to create a `Result` with an array of `T`, when your completion expect a single `T` value.

The `values: [String: T]` build up a list of `T` in your for loop:

```swift
for resource in resources {
  // here value is a T
  values[resource.description] = value
}
```

The flattened values variable is the result of a compact map of your `values` dictionary

```swift
let flattenedValues = resources.compactMap({ values[$0.description] }).flatMap({ $0 })
```

This means at this point, the type of `flattenedValues` is `[T]`.

The completion (`(Result<T?, Error>) -> Void`) expect a `Result` with a single value of type `T`, but you're are trying to resolve it with an array (`[T]`).
This is why you are getting this error.

**Solution:**

From what I understand, you want to fetch your entities from multiple resources (`FetchResource`), which mean you probably want to always return an array of entities (`[T]`).

If so, you can just change your `RepoCompletion` to an array: `[T]`. This would look like this:

```swift
// change RepoCompletion<T> to RepoCompletion<[T]>
public func fetch<T: Entity>(_ resources: [FetchResource<T>], completion: @escaping RepoCompletion<[T]>) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I understand the error thrown. The thing is that T is already an array. Maybe `Entity` is confusing you. Let's replace it with `Codable` for instance. I don't want to specify the result to be [T], I prefer to indicate it in the T value itself because an array of Codables are already a Codable.
The thing that confuses me is the part when I check the type of the values, which is really the problem I don't understand.

Comment: `T` is actually not an array, `T` is anything that conforms to `Codable`. It can be an array, but also a `String` or a custom `struct`. You wrote your code having in mind `T` is an array, which is not true. And form what I see, there is now way your `fetch` method can return a single result (like a `struct` or a `String`).